# Как правильно получить значение php из xml?

Tags: php, xml

Пытаюсь взять информацию из нужного пункта `xml`, и сохранить значение в переменную.
Но что-то не выходит это сделать. Как правильно такое сделать?

Нужно получить пройтись по пунктам: `info -> traffic -> level` и сохранить значение в переменную. Сам пробовал так:

```
$level = $childs->{'info'}->{'traffic'}->{'level'}->nodeValue;
```

адрес `xml` которую хочу распарсить: https://export.yandex.ru/bar/reginfo.xml?region=3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте это:

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file('https://export.yandex.ru/bar/reginfo.xml?region=3') or die('Error: Cannot create object');
foreach ($xml->traffic as $item) {
    echo $item->level;
}
?>
```

А если `level` всегда в том файле только один будет, тогда можно вот так:

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file('https://export.yandex.ru/bar/reginfo.xml?region=3') or die('Error: Cannot create object');
$array = array();
foreach ($xml->traffic as $item) {
    $array[] = $item->level;
}
$level = implode(',',$array);
?>
```